# GWT Developer plugin For IE installation problem

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt, plugins

I'm using a windows 7 (32 bit) box with IE8 and i'm having issues 
installing GWT Developer plugin For IE.

I get the following error message: "Installer download failed. Error code = 0x80072efe "

the installer stays stuck at the "downloading plugin" stage.

i've made sure my windows 7 firewall is off and also turned off my antivirus program but still same problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most users trying to install the GWT devmode plugin for IE8 on Windows 7 (Vista) 32-bit were able to use the following script from a command line (replace "Foo" with your Windows User Name):

regsvr32.exe "C:\Users\Foo\AppData\Local\Google\Google Web Toolkit\Developer Plugin\IE\oophm.dll"

Also, make sure you are downloading the installer from the browser prompt to your desktop and installing from your desktop. Your error is from an earlier installer, which I think conflicts with your version of GWT.

Users trying to install for IE9 will not be able to install unless they add a specification to the doctype to force IE9 to render as IE8, per this post from Google...

http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/12/support-for-gwt-dev-mode-in-ie-9.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it works if you do an offline installation using the MSI from here: http://ui-programming.blogspot.com/2009/12/update-your-application-to-gwt-20.html

Comment: unfortunately it didn't worked. i guess i'm having a serious system inconsistency in my windows 7 installation but i'm not able to figure out what the cause of the problem. here is the same question i  posted in gwt google group with discussion i had with Fabio from gwt google group : http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/638ece42a21ac379 - can someone further propose what i can do to figure out this serious problem i'm facing? -thanks much

Answer (score 0):

the gwt team has provided a temporary solution to this problem.

you can check the solution at the gwt google groups thread discussion:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/638ece42a21ac379

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/ie/prebuilt/

Comment: More explanation would help OP and you.